# Background isn't changing as it should - Jquery/Javascript/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-image

Javascript noob alert!

I have to make a bit of a complicated site right now, but I simplified it to focus in my problem.

[Check Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKbwXY)

Basically, it's gonna have 3 images (represented by the colors) that should appear as the user presses prev and next. I can't use 3rd party slides, I need to follow this logic for, as I stated previously, the final site is quite complicated.

I don't understand why my JS doesn't work. I do think it's inneficient and I could write better than that (and I'll accept tips regarding this), but I don't see the mistake. If you browse just a little, you'll see that either the prev or the next button stop working after the 1st slide.

Any help is appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.first').on('click', '.next', function() {
    $('body').addClass("second");
    $('body').removeClass("third");
    $('body').removeClass("first");
    event.preventDefault();
  })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.first').on('click', '.prev', function() {
    $('body').addClass("third");
    $('body').removeClass("second");
    $('body').removeClass("first");
    event.preventDefault();
  })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.second').on('click', '.prev', function() {
    $('body').removeClass("third");
    $('body').addClass("first");
    $('body').removeClass("second");
    event.preventDefault();
  })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.second').on('click', '.next', function() {
    $('body').addClass("third");
    $('body').removeClass("first");
    $('body').removeClass("second");
    event.preventDefault();
  })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.third').on('click', '.prev', function() {
    $('body').removeClass("first");
    $('body').addClass("second");
    event.preventDefault();
  })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.third').on('click', '.next', function() {
    $('body').removeClass("second");
    $('body').addClass("first");
    $('body').removeClass("third");
    event.preventDefault();
  })
});
```

```css
.first {
  background-color: #0ff;
}
.second {
  background-color: #000;
}
.third {
  background-color: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="first">
  <nav class="slides-navigation">
    <a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a>
    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: in codepen its working.

Comment: Weird, surely it isn't my computer? I've tried different browsers.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain properly, they should loop. When I reach yellow for example, the prev button stops working, and that's not what I want to happen.

Comment: ok got it. this way its not woking

Comment: bcoz you are trying to select the .second and .third it is not there in your available dom. i am writing code for you. just wait for few minutes .

Comment: Firstly, if you wish to support Firefox, you have to pass `event` as function handler parameter. FF doesn't use global event model. Secondly, your code needs some refactorization, you should just delegate event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no need to complicate your life with such code for something so simple.

```js
var nums = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
var curr = 0;

$('.next, .prev').on('click', function(e) {
  // check which button is clicked and modify the curr value according to it
  var offset = $(this).hasClass('prev') ? nums.length - 1 : 1;
  curr = (curr + offset) % nums.length;          // avoid being out of index
  $('body').removeClass();
  $('body').addClass(nums[curr]);
})
```

```css
.first {background-color: #0ff;}
.second {background-color: #000;}
.third {background-color: #ff0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="first">
  <nav class="slides-navigation">
    <a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a>
    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
  </nav>
</body>
```

---

The reason your code wasn't working as expected is because you bind those 6 event listeners, but only 1 of the 3 elements exist at the time the code runs. You **were** using the delegated listeners, but not in the proper way. To make it work, you'd need to first select the non-changeable parent element and in your case that would be a html element or the document since you're changing the body classes. So, something like:

```
$(document)...
```

instead of:

```
$('body')...
```

Comment: You're welcome! And thank you. :)  I just added an explanation telling why your code was not working as expected.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I'll have to write more things based on this code, hopefully I can do it without asking here again :D

Comment: Haha, don't worry about asking here again, that is what we are here for. Do you understand the first line of my event handler (`curr = ...`) or you want me to break it down for you?

Comment: Just updated it, hopefully it's easier to understand now. I'm just traversing indexes without going out of range.

Answer (score 3):

Check this hope it will helpful to you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', 'body.first .next', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('body').addClass("second");
    $('body').removeClass("third");
    $('body').removeClass("first");

  })

  $(document).on('click', 'body.first .prev', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('body').addClass("third");
    $('body').removeClass("second");
    $('body').removeClass("first");

  })

  $(document).on('click', 'body.second .prev', function() {

    event.preventDefault();
    $('body').removeClass("third");
    $('body').addClass("first");
    $('body').removeClass("second");

  })


  $(document).on('click', 'body.second .next', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('body').addClass("third");
    $('body').removeClass("first");
    $('body').removeClass("second");

  })

  $(document).on('click', 'body.third .prev', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('body').removeClass("first");
    $('body').addClass("second");

  })

  $(document).on('click', 'body.third  .next', function() {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('body').removeClass("second");
    $('body').addClass("first");
    $('body').removeClass("third");

  })
});
```

```css
.first {
  background-color: #0ff;
}
.second {
  background-color: #000;
}
.third {
  background-color: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="first">
  <nav class="slides-navigation">
    <a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a>
    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Even though the other answer is shorter, I may still use this. I need to associate other classes to first, second and third, but I'll check first if I can write something more efficient with Shomz code.

Comment: you can try Shomz code it is really optimized code.

Comment: @AndreaSantana, this is a really bad code(although it fixed the original issue). When even you see something repeated twice in the code, it means you're doing something wrong. And if you repeat something six times... you understand :)  If you want to make combinations or different behaviours, you can still use something similar to mine, but use an object, for example, denoting where to go for each button for each class (meaning, clicking "next" on red bg changes it to green, clicking "prev" changes it to yellow, etc.).

Comment: @webdeveloper Please optimize it at least a little bit - this way you're teaching beginners some really bad practices. :)

Comment: It is, just not sure I can expand it with my current skills. But I'll try.

Comment: @AndreaSantana Remember one of the programming rules: **DRY** - Don't Repeat Yourself

Comment: @webdeveloper Sorry if I sounded a little harsh, but that's just too much code for such simple functionality, right? (I know the original code is not yours, of course)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. you are really great. Shomz

Comment: What ever the question was there from that only i modified.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, I know, sorry. Let me at least indent it for you. An upvote from me. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this, you can accommodate any number of classes with this code. Just add class to the array `classArr`

in javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    var classArr = ["first", "second", "third"];

    $('body').on('click', '.next, .prev', function(event) {
        $(this).hasClass("next") ? counter++ : counter--;
        changeClass();
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    function changeClass(){
        var indexClass = counter % classArr.length;
        indexClass = Math.abs(indexClass);
        $.each(classArr, function(index, value) {
            if (index == indexClass) {
                $('body').addClass(classArr[index]);
            } else {
                $('body').removeClass(classArr[index]);
            }
        });
     }

});
```

see the js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/95hwwt8u/2/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 0;
  var classArr = ["first", "second", "third"];

  $('body').on('click', '.next, .prev', function(event) {
        $(this).hasClass("next") ? counter++ : counter--;
        changeClass();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
  
  function changeClass(){
    var indexClass = counter % classArr.length;
    indexClass = Math.abs(indexClass);
    $.each(classArr, function(index, value) {
      if (index == indexClass) {
        $('body').addClass(classArr[index]);
      } else {
        $('body').removeClass(classArr[index]);
      }
    });
  }

});
```

```css
.first{
 background-color:#0ff;
 background-position: center -47px
}
.second{
 background-color:#000;
     background-position: center -47px
}
.third{
 background-color:#ff0;
 background-position: center -47px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="first">
  <nav class="slides-navigation">    
          <a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a>
          <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
   

 $(function() {
      
    
    $('#slide').on('click','.next',function(){
          if($('body').hasClass("first")){
           $('body').removeClass("first");
              $('body').addClass("second");
              event.preventDefault();
          } else  if($('body').hasClass("second")){
              $('body').removeClass("second");
              $('body').addClass("third");
              event.preventDefault();
          }  else  if($('body').hasClass("third")){
                $('body').removeClass("third");
                $('body').addClass("first");
                event.preventDefault();
           }                                       
       });
    
       
     
       
    
    $('#slide').on('click','.prev',function(){
                if($('body').hasClass("first")){
              $('body').removeClass("first");
                    $('body').addClass("third");
                    event.preventDefault();
                } else  if($('body').hasClass("second")){
                    $('body').removeClass("second");
                    $('body').addClass("first");
                    event.preventDefault();
                }  else  if($('body').hasClass("third")){
              $('body').removeClass("third");
                    $('body').addClass("second");
                    event.preventDefault();
                }                                       
             });
          });
```

```css
.first {
  background-color: #0ff;
}
.second {
  background-color: #000;
}
.third {
  background-color: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
     <body id='slide' class="first">
           <nav class="slides-navigation">   
              <a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a>
              <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
           </nav>
       </body>
```